# Determine play framework action from Router

Tags: playframework

I have a filter that I'm using in my play application. I have a single case for this filter to modify its behaviour. I need a way to determine which actions match this case.

My thoughts currently are to either build a list of annotated controller actions, or check for actions of a specific type.

Currently my filter has the play.api.routing.Router injected.

How would I determine which action the current request would be handled by?

Is it possible to determine the underlying action from its wrapping filter?

EDIT (adding test setup):

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  def test1= Action {
    Results.Ok
  }

  def test2 = Action {
    Results.Ok
  }
}
```

Which is then bound by

```
new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .configure(c)
  .bindings(new RouterTagsTestModule(c))
  .overrides(
    bind[Router].to(Router.from {
      case play.api.routing.sird.GET(p"/test1") => MyController.test1
      case play.api.routing.sird.GET(p"/test2") => MyController.test2
    })
  ).build()
```

Comment: So you want to know, in your filter, which method will handle the current url (ex: "/login" --> LoginCtrl.processLogin())?

Comment: Yes, in such a way that I can either check the Action class. Or check if the method was annotated.

Comment: The method name could work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
import play.api.routing.Router.Tags

// Inside your Filter#apply method
// reqHeader: RequestHeader
val ctrl = reqHeader.tags.get(Tags.RouteController)
val method = reqHeader.tags.get(Tags.RouteActionMethod)
val verb = reqHeader.tags.get(Tags.RouteVerb)
```

Note that those variables are `Option[String]`, so in case there is no matching action you will get `None`

Comment: Thanks, I'll run a test now.

Comment: With numerous attempts I can't quite find a test that has these tags populated.

Comment: Marking this as correct, because I'm sure it is. Sadly can't seem to wrap a test around it. I suspect it's the play generated routed that does the tagging and overriding it drops this feature.

Perhaps if I could find a way to inject a test controller into the generated router...but that's another issue.

Comment: @ArjunSol Are you checking this inside a filter? I have only tested it there and those fields were populated...

Comment: Yes its inside the filter, but with an application built by GuiceApplicationBuilder.

The router gets overridden to supply different routes to check, I suspect this is why the tagging gets dropped.